# future local variable doesn't save the value and returns null

Tags: flutter

I've assigned a value for a local variable inside a function (`Future`), but the result always gives a `null` value. Is there any wrong code in my code?

```js
enum StatusUser { telahMasuk, belumMasuk, berhasilMasuk, gagalMasuk }

class MyClass {
  Future<StatusUser> muatSeting(String? key) async {
    StatusUser? sp;

    final data = await getUserData();
    try {
      if (data != null) {
        final dataToken = jsonDecode(
            APIUser().decodeJWT(data['token'].toString().split('.')[1]));
        if (new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                dataToken['tgl_verify'] <
            864000) {
          sp = StatusUser.telahMasuk;
        }
      } else {
        sp = StatusUser.belumMasuk;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return sp!;
  }
}
```

When I debugging, its shows `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`.  Whereas at previous version of Flutter, it works. I want that this `future` returning an enum value from variable `sp`.

```bash
❯ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-38-generic, locale id_ID.UTF-8)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: There are two code paths that neglect to set `sp`.

Comment: its like `condition == true ? <sp for true condition> : <sp for false condition> `

Comment: No, I'm saying there are two possible ways for your code to execute that each neglect to set `sp`.   Orbital Bombardment's answer pointed out one of them.  The other is if an exception is thrown and you enter your `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

The null check operator is failing here because `sp` is null.

```
return sp!;
```

Looking from the if statement, I think this condition fails `(new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - dataToken['tgl_verify'] < 864000)` and therefore `sp` is never set.

```
if (data != null) {
    final dataToken = jsonDecode(
        APIUser().decodeJWT(data['token'].toString().split('.')[1]));
    if (new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch -
            dataToken['tgl_verify'] <
        864000) { // this if statement never runs so sp is null.
      sp = StatusUser.telahMasuk;
    }
  }
```

Comment: and what caused it?, because the condition has result, and if `data` is null, is it should resulting `sp = StatusUser.belumMasuk` ?

Comment: @pras No, the `else` block that sets `sp` belongs to a different `if`.  You should ensure that `sp` is set along *all* code paths (or give it a non-`null` default value).

Answer (score 1):

If you want `StatusUser.belumMasuk` to be returned by default, then you either should initialize `sp` to use that as its default value:

```dart
Future<StatusUser> muatSeting(String? key) async {
  StatusUser sp = StatusUser.belumMasuk;

  final data = await getUserData();
  try {
    if (data != null) {
      final dataToken = jsonDecode(
          APIUser().decodeJWT(data['token'].toString().split('.')[1]));
      if (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - dataToken['tgl_verify'] <
          864000) {
        sp = StatusUser.telahMasuk;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return sp;
}
```

or use the `??` operator:

```dart
Future<StatusUser> muatSeting(String? key) async {
  StatusUser? sp;

  final data = await getUserData();
  try {
    if (data != null) {
      final dataToken = jsonDecode(
          APIUser().decodeJWT(data['token'].toString().split('.')[1]));
      if (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - dataToken['tgl_verify'] <
          864000) {
        sp = StatusUser.telahMasuk;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return sp ?? StatusUser.belumMasuk;
}
```

Both cases would allow you to remove the `else` blocks and additionally would handle the case where an exception is thrown within the `try` block. (Incidentally, you should [avoid `catch`es without `on` clauses](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses).)

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75925678/), you made a remark:

> I'm in confuse with 'why nested *if* (child) when without *else* and false condition dosen't returning value that was set on *else* from parent *if*'

Why would it?  That's not how `if`-`else` works.  The outer `else` block corresponds *only* to the outer `if` condition.

Imagine:

```dart
if (condition1) {
  if (condition2) {
    doStuff();
  }

  doLotsOfOtherStuff();
} else {
  handleCondition1Failed();
}
```

If `condition2` is `false`, do you expect `doLotsOfOtherStuff()` to be skipped?  But if so, then `doLotsOfOtherStuff()` should be moved to be within the `if (condition2)` block.  Do you expect `doLotsOfOtherStuff()` *and* `handleCondition1Failed()` to both be executed?  Either of those choices would be unintuitive and very hard to follow for most people.

If you want the `else` block to be executed if either `condition1` or `condition2` fails, then you should write it as:

```dart
var succeeded = false;

if (condition1) {
  if (condition2) {
    doStuff();
    succeeded = true;
  }

  doLotsOfOtherStuff();
}

if (!succeeded) {
  handleFailure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with adding `else` on nested `if`

```js
if (data != null) {
    final dataToken = jsonDecode(
        APIUser().decodeJWT(data['token'].toString().split('.')[1]));
    if (new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch -
            dataToken['tgl_verify'] < 864000) {
        sp = StatusUser.telahMasuk;
    } else {
        sp = StatusUser.belumMasuk;
    }
  } else {
    sp = StatusUser.belumMasuk;
  }
```

I'm in confuse with 'why nested *if* (child) when without *else* and false condition dosen't returning value that was set on *else* from parent *if*'

Comment: This still neglects to set `sp` to a non-`null` value if an exception is thrown.